# How SqlDataAdapter works internally?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, internals, sqldataadapter

I wonder how `SqlDataAdapter` works internally, especially when using `UpdateCommand` for updating a huge `DataTable` (since it's usually a lot faster that just sending sql statements from a loop).

Here is some idea I have in mind :

- It creates a prepared sql statement (using `SqlCommand.Prepare()`) with `CommandText` filled and sql parameters initialized with correct sql types. Then, it loops on datarows that need to be updated, and for each record, it updates parameters values, and call `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.
- It creates a bunch of `SqlCommand` objects with everything filled inside (`CommandText` and sql parameters). Several SqlCommands at once are then batched to the server (depending of `UpdateBatchSize`).
- It uses some special, low level or undocumented sql driver instructions that allow to perform an update on several rows in a effecient way (rows to update would need to be provided using a special data format and a the same sql query (`UpdateCommand` here) would be executed against each of these rows).

Comment: I often wonder why people that ask how certain things work internally don't use something like ILSpy and just take a peek.

Comment: I'm assuming you've hooked up a profiler (to the database) to see what it does?  What is your question?

Comment: As @itsme86 has mentioned, you can have a lot of fun with ILSpy - http://ilspy.net/. Use Open From GAC to add a reference to System.Data and explore away!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses an internal facility of the SQL Server client classes which is called **command sets**. You can send multiple batches with a single command to SQL Server. This cuts down on per-call overhead. You have less server roundtrips and such.

A single row is updated per statement, and one statement per batch is sent, but multiple batches per roundtrip are send. The last point in this list is the *magic sauce*.

Unfortunately, this facility is **not publicly exposed**. [Ayende took a hack on this and built a private-reflection bases API for it.](http://ayende.com/blog/1679/opening-up-query-batching)

If you want more information I encourage you to look at the internal `SqlCommandSet` class.

That said, **you can go faster than this by yourself**: Transfer the update data using a TVP and issue a single `UPDATE` that updates many rows. That way you save all per-batch, per-roundtrip and per-statement overheads.

Such a query would look like this:

```
update T set T.x = @src.x from T join @src on T.ID = @src.ID
```

Comment: Good answer; although the last statement does depend on the nature of the update. I'd possibly add a link to ILSpy and highlight that the SqlCommandSet is a private field in `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: @dash I cannot think of a case where this would not be the fastest way for many-row updates. Can you think of one?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear - I agree, I meant to say in the context of the original post that if you've updated many different rows with many different values then there isn't really a single SQL statement you can use (is there?!)

Comment: @dash, you can say `update T set T.x = @src.x from T join @src on T.ID = @src.ID`. That updates everything at once, pulling data from the TVP. *Very* efficient for index and indexed-view maintenance.

Comment: I see! I haven't come across TVP before. I shall now (ritually ab)use them - being able to supply a table to a stored proc or function is *very* useful. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1483/using-table-valued-parameters-tvp-in-sql-server-2008/